# why create framesetter with chinese text was extremly slow in iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text

I found that use CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString to create framesetter with chinese string in iOS5 was very slow, but in iOS4, it's fast.

I have run a test like this: 
(chinese.txt contain 77571 chinese chars and english.txt contain 233727 chars)

```
 NSString *englishCtn = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self documentDirectory], @"english.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 NSAttributedString *englishCtnA = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:englishCtn];
 NSString *chineseCtn = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self documentDirectory], @"chinese.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 NSAttributedString *chineseCtnA = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:chineseCtn];

double start = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)englishCtnA);
NSLog(@"english length:%d time %f", englishCtn.length, ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - start) * 1000);

start = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)chineseCtnA);
NSLog(@"chinese length:%d time %f", chineseCtnA.length, ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - start) * 1000);
```

in iOS 5 the result is :

chinese length:77571 time:12140.347004

english length:233727 time:75.886011

in iOS 4 the result is :

chinese length:77571 time:53.114176

english length:233727 time:55.696011

I use xCode tool time profiler to see what happen, i found that the function TRun::GetNextLigatureCandidateCharRange(long) take most of the time, I don't know how to optimize, help

Answer (score 0):

The C++ portions of the runtime were largely, if not entirely added in iOS 5, and that is where it fails.  To me that suggests that you should file a bug report with apple, or open an inquiry on your account if you have any remaining.

Comment: e...I don't know what you mean

Comment: Wait...is that function (GetNextLigature...) yours or the runtime's?

Comment: Right, so something has changed to make it slow.  As far as I can tell it is a bug in the new iOS 5 implementation.  No matter what you do, you can't change that function so I suggest contacting Apple.

Comment: there must be some solution, otherwise why ebook reader like stanze/ibook can be so fast